# System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have searched on different sites but couldn't find  the exact solution. Here is my code kindly help me how to fix that error I will be really thankful to you. I have close connection at the end of each method but I am having that error and when I comment it out another error come "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed"

```
private void Count()
{
    int count;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;


    string selectedcmd = "SELECT COUNT(Review_rate) AS Review_count FROM Review WHERE (Paper_id = '" + Session["PaperID"] + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, dbcon);
    dbcon.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(0));


        if (count < 3)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Review_submit.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            average();
        }
    }
    dbcon.Close();
}

private void average()
{
    int avg;
    SqlDataReader reader1 = null;


    string selectedValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
    Response.Write(selectedValue);
    dbcon.Open();
    string selectedcmd = "SELECT AVG(Review_rate) AS AVG,COUNT(Review_rate) as Review_count  FROM  Review WHERE (Paper_id ='" + Session["PaperID"] + "') GROUP BY Paper_id HAVING (COUNT(Review_rate)>= 3)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, dbcon);

    reader1= cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
        avg = Convert.ToInt32(reader1.GetInt32(0));


        if (avg < 3)
        {
            if (reader1.HasRows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [User].User_email FROM [User] INNER JOIN Paper ON [User].User_id = Paper.User_id WHERE ([User].User_id =Paper.User_id) AND (Paper.Paper_id ='" + Session["PaperID"] + "')", dbcon);
                // SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [User].User_email FROM [User] INNER JOIN Paper ON [User].User_id = Paper.User_id WHERE ([User].User_id ='2') AND (Paper.Paper_id ='2')", dbcon);
                string result = (string)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                // {
                //   Label1.Text = result;
                // }

                StringBuilder bodyMsg = new StringBuilder();
                //email = Email.Text;
                bodyMsg.Append("Your paper is rejected");
                // bodyMsg.Append("<br /><br /><a href=http://localhost:7401/SendEmailConfirmationSample/Login.aspx?ID=" + email.ToString() + ">Activate Your Account</a>");
                bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                // bodyMsg.AppendFormat("Registered Email: {0}", email);
                NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("salmacms26@gmail.com", "salma@cms");
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("salmacms26@gmail.com");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(result));
                msg.Subject = "Reviews Announcment";
                msg.Body = bodyMsg.ToString();
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = loginInfo;
                client.Send(msg);


                //Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                if(reader1.HasRows)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [User].User_email FROM [User] INNER JOIN Paper ON [User].User_id = Paper.User_id WHERE ([User].User_id =Paper.User_id) AND (Paper.Paper_id ='" + Session["PaperID"] + "')", dbcon);
                    // SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [User].User_email FROM [User] INNER JOIN Paper ON [User].User_id = Paper.User_id WHERE ([User].User_id ='2') AND (Paper.Paper_id ='2')", dbcon);
                    string result = (string)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        Label1.Text = result;
                    }

                    StringBuilder bodyMsg = new StringBuilder();
                    //email = Email.Text;
                    bodyMsg.Append("Your paper is accepted");
                    // bodyMsg.Append("<br /><br /><a href=http://localhost:7401/SendEmailConfirmationSample/Login.aspx?ID=" + email.ToString() + ">Activate Your Account</a>");
                    bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                    bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                    bodyMsg.Append("<br />");
                    // bodyMsg.AppendFormat("Registered Email: {0}", email);
                    NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("salmacms26@gmail.com", "salma@cms");
                    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                    msg.From = new MailAddress("salmacms26@gmail.com");
                    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(result));
                    msg.Subject = "Reviews Announcment";
                    msg.Body = bodyMsg.ToString();
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = loginInfo;
                    client.Send(msg);


                    //Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
        dbcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the exception occur?

Comment: in line 84 after average query ..in dbcon.Open()

Comment: what should i do kindly help me i will be really thankful to you

Comment: These are the results that you would expect when using unnecessary global variables

Comment: global variables? sorry i didn't got your point

Comment: dbCon in this context is a global variable, defined at the class level and so it could be modified by any method in this class. The use of global variables is a well known problem for the maintenability and robustness of any kind of program

Comment: @kristenstewart Steve is suggesting you make the `dbcon` variable a local variable (declared inside the `Count` method's body) instead of a field (declare as a member of the class).

Answer (score 1):

Your `average` method tries to open a connection that has *already* been opened by `Count`.

First off, you have to be careful not to open the connection a second time without closing it first.

Also:

- Instead of explicitly calling `Close` on the connection, you should be using the `using` statement, since the connection implements the `IDisposable` interface
- I'd reduce the scope of the connection to be a local variable in `Count`, and pass it as an argument to `average`, like so:

```
private void Count()
{
    string selectedcmd = "SELECT COUNT(Review_rate) AS Review_count FROM Review WHERE (Paper_id = '" + Session["PaperID"] + "')";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //more code
                average(conn);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void average(SqlConnection conn)
{
    //use the connection passed as an argument
}
```

The `using` statement will take care of disposing of the connection and the command, *even* if an exception occurs. Your current code won't close the connection if an excepion occurs.

Comment: it means i should not open the connection again in average method right?

Comment: @kristenstewart Yes. See my updated answer. More importantly, you should use a local variable for `conn`, instead of using a class-level field (like Steve suggested in the comments).

Comment: where to close connection @dcastro

Comment: @kristenstewart If you use the `using` statements like I suggested, the statement will automatically close the connection for you.

Comment: i have used your code ..now i am facing this error ..ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: ahh...:( :( i am fed up now please what should i do now

Comment: @kristenstewart You have to use the reader *inside* the brackets: `using(connection) { conn.Open(); //use reader here }`

Comment: i have used it in brackets like that using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, dbcon))
            {

                
                reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    avg = Convert.ToInt32(reader1.GetInt32(0));

Comment: Edit your question and add your new code at the bottom, and tell us where the exception happened.

Comment: now i am pasting other  string selectedcmd = "SELECT AVG(Review_rate) AS Expr1 FROM Review WHERE (Paper_id = '" + Session["PaperID"] + "')GROUP BY Paper_id HAVING (AVG(Review_rate) >= 3)";using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(conn))using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, dbcon)){reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();while (reader1.Read()){avg = Convert.ToInt32(reader1.GetInt32(0));if (avg < 3)

Comment: @kristenstewart You're passing `dbconn` to the `SqlCommand` constructor, you should be passing `conn` instead. Delete all your connection, command, and reader fields, like `dbconn` and `reader1`, and make everything a local variable.

Comment: conn is connection string ..dbcon is sql connection

Answer (score 0):

Do not use global variables for keeping the Connection.
Start using the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to be sure to close correctly these preciuos resources..

For example

```
private void Count()
{
    .....

    using(SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectedcmd, dbcon))
    {
         dbcon.Open();
         using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  ......
              }
         } // Here the reader goes out of scope and it is closed and disposed
    }// Here the connection is closed and together with the command is disposed
}
```

This will remove your problem because the Using Statement will close and dispose every disposable object referenced in the start of its block

As a side note, not related to your problem. String concatenation could be very dangerous for the security of your db ([Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)). So, the Session["ID"] value should be passed to your query using a [parameterized approach](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)